# npm ERR! updating Angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to update Angular2 to Angular 4 using this comand:

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save
```

And shows this error:

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Windows\temp\npm-3816-28e571ea\registry.npmjs.org\typescript\-\typescript-2.4.1.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: c3ccb16ddaa0b2314de031e7e6fee89e5ba346bc
npm ERR! Actual:   e123d8d94948e846a2c38ac3ffea38ea349ec2ec
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-2.4.1.tgz

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\U\Ov15\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-07T02_21_38_894Z-debug.log
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: Clear your npm cache and try again. `npm cache clean`

Comment: If you are accessing via corporate network, you have to set proxy by executing  npm config set proxy "http://<domain>%5C<username>:<password>@<servername>:<port>/"
npm config set https-proxy "http://<domain>%5C<username>:<password>@<servername>:<port>/". Or you can manually edit the config file by executing "npm config edit"

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your npm proxy?

npm config set **http-proxy** http://username:password@ip:port

npm config set **https-proxy** http://username:password@ip:port